# Removing repeated string values

Tags: sql

Given a non-key varchar column where the string values may be repeated in many other rows, is a separate table mapping unique strings from the column to an integer a beneficial practice? It would clearly eliminate storage space, but is the performance lost from joining the first table to this mapping table worth it?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking integer comparisons are going to be faster because at the lowest levels the machine does these singly as opposed to each character in the string.

However whether conversion is a good idea or not is a difficult question without knowing how often the comparison takes place.

Personally speaking I the conversion was likely to take place often (such as a key look up in a join) then I'd make make them integers.

The same things holds for indexing, and also because the indexes are smaller (space efficiency) you remove some backing store latency - again that's the theory - but in reality there may be many many other factors to consider.

Answer (score 0):

Commonly referred to as a Lookup table, it's definitely worth adding if it the values repeat frequently, and if the strings are substantial enough, ie: a 2-character `State` code is not worth the trouble.

Integer comparisons are faster than string comparisons, but this is typically more about space savings than performance, because you've already got the string in-row, so separating the repeating values into a lookup table adds an extra `JOIN`.  It's a step towards normalization, but there is such a thing as over-normalization, in my opinion, whether or not you should depends on what your data is like, and how it's used.